# vb.net Webbrowser InvokeMember Click Help

Tags: vb.net, browser, invoke

Ive only messed with InvokeMember Click afew times and ive been having problems with this one.

Here is a Firebug screenshot of the HTML.

[image: Screenshot from FireBug]

I am trying to WebBrowser1 InvokeMember "Click" on the OK button, but I have no idea how to work it with classes, and 2 of them at that. So obviously Im going to have to do some loop and get the second one.

I don't know where to even start SO i was wondering if someone could provide a basic snippit if possible, please and thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Im going to admit this was my first stop after researching it, but i took an alternate root and I didnt go for the class name but went for the innerhtml inside the link and this is what ive come up with and it works:

```
Dim PageElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")

For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElements
    If InStr(CurElement.InnerHtml, "<B>OK</B><I></I>") Then
        CurElement.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
```